# Recursive function inside class with foreach changes public value where it shouldn't

Tags: php, class, recursion, foreach, hierarchical

Ok, I'm really stucked with this. I hope you can help me.

I have my class, used to manage hierarchical data. The input is a plain array with the following structure (just an example):

```
$list = array(
(object) array('id' => 1, 'nombre' => 'Cámaras de fotos', 'parentId' => null),
(object) array('id' => 2, 'nombre' => 'Lentes', 'parentId' => null),
(object) array('id' => 3, 'nombre' => 'Zoom', 'parentId' => 2),
(object) array('id' => 4, 'nombre' => 'SLR', 'parentId' => 1),
(object) array('id' => 5, 'nombre' => 'Primarios', 'parentId' => 2),
(object) array('id' => 6, 'nombre' => 'Sensor APS-C', 'parentId' => 4),
(object) array('id' => 7, 'nombre' => 'Full-frame', 'parentId' => 4),
(object) array('id' => 8, 'nombre' => 'Flashes', 'parentId' => null),
(object) array('id' => 9, 'nombre' => 'Compactas', 'parentId' => 1)
);
```

I input the data to the class this way:

```
$Hierarchical = new Hierarchical;
$Hierarchical->plain = $list;
```

Then I have a public function (`createTree`) to create a multidimensional array representation of the list. It works perfectly. It can return the result or store it inside `$this->tree`.

As you can see, this is very simple. It calls private function `iterateTree`, which is the recursive function.

```
class Hierarchical {

    public $plain = array();
    public $tree = array();

    public function createTree($parentId=0, $return=false) {

    $tree = $this->iterateTree($parentId);

    if(!$return) {
        $this->tree = $tree;
    } else {
        return $tree;
    }

    }


    private function iterateTree($parentId) {

    $resArray = array();

    foreach($this->plain as $item) {

        if($item->parentId == $parentId) {

            $children = $this->iterateTree($item->id);

            if( count($children) > 0 ) {
                $item->children = $children;
            }

            $resArray[] = $item;

        }

    }

    return $resArray;

    } 

}
```

So far so good. It works fine.

**BUT...** The problem appears when I want to use `$this->plain` after calling `createTree()`. Instead of returning the original dataset, it returns some kind of mix between the original input, with all their children appended (similar to `$this->tree`).

I can't figure out why the content of `$this->plain` is being changed, neither in the both functions used I'm changing it's content.

I've tried unseting the variables inside the `foreach`, after the `foreach`, even passing the original array as an argument and not using `$this->plain` at all inside the recursive function. Nothing worked.

I'm also **not** using any other function inside the class that could change it's value.

It's a total mistery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach` loop `$item` will be a reference to the object in the array, so you are changing that same object in the line

```
$item->children = $children;
```

This will affect the object referred to in the original arrays `$list` and `$this->plain`.

One solution may be to clone `$item` within your foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

According to Doug's answer, the correct function is: (added `$itemAux = clone $item`)

```
private function iterateTree($parentId) {

    $resArray = array();

    foreach($this->plain as $item) {

        $itemAux = clone $item;

        if($itemAux->parentId == $parentId) {

            $children = $this->iterateTree($itemAux->id);

            if( count($children) > 0 ) {
                $itemAux->children = $children;
            }

            $resArray[] = $itemAux;

        }

    }

    return $resArray;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Doug's answer, although the manual says that "objects are *not* passed by reference" (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php), it may instead help to think of objects as a completely separate entity from any variables that may "contain" them, and that they are actually passed everywhere by reference...

```
class testClass
{
    public $var1 = 1;
}

function testFunc($obj)
{
    $obj->var1 = 2;
}


$t = new testClass;
testFunc($t);
echo $t->var1; // 2
```

So when you do `$item->children = $children;`, you are in fact affecting each original object in that `$plain` array.